# Does Android have an equivalent to iOS secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint?

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, avaudiosession

Trying to find a cross platform way to detect if another app is playing media. I don't care what it is, just if it's playing or not. Specifically looking for the equivalent of these two.

[secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616600-secondaryaudioshouldbesilencedhi)

[silenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616622-silencesecondaryaudiohintnotific)

I found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager) which looks similar, but all of the functions in here require `Manifest.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL` which isn't available for third party apps.

Comment: Unclear if you've seen: https://developer.android.com/media/optimize/audio-focus

Comment: @MorrisonChang I believe what I want is more like [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#isMusicActive()). Sucks it doesn't have some kind of signal but it appears it might do...